# Dijkstra shortest path algorithm: finding number of checked vertices

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

At the moment I have an application that calculates the shortest path of a weighted graph based on Robert Sedgewick's code.

Want I want to do is count the weight of a path, the length of that path and the number of vertices that have been checked.
I have succeeded in finding the first two, but finding the amount of vertices that have been checked isn't really working.

To give an example of what I want to do:

I want to find out how many of the squares have been checked by a red line in the following image:
http://prntscr.com/9921cv

Any clues on how to start would be really welcome.

This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
public class Dijkstra {

private double[] distTo;          // distTo[v] = distance  of shortest s->v path
private DirectedEdge[] edgeTo;    // edgeTo[v] = last edge on shortest s->v path
private IndexMinPQ<Double> pq;    // priority queue of vertices
private int length;               // length of a path


/**
 * Computes a shortest paths tree from <tt>s</tt> to every other vertex in
 * the edge-weighted digraph <tt>G</tt>.
 * @param G the edge-weighted digraph
 * @param s the source vertex
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if an edge weight is negative
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException unless 0 &le; <tt>s</tt> &le; <tt>V</tt> - 1
 */
public Dijkstra(EdgeWeightedDigraph G, int s) {
    for (DirectedEdge e : G.edges()) {

        if (e.weight() < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("edge " + e + " has negative weight");
        }
    }

    distTo = new double[G.V()];
    edgeTo = new DirectedEdge[G.V()];

    for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++) {
        distTo[v] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    }
    distTo[s] = 0.0;

    // relax vertices in order of distance from s
    pq = new IndexMinPQ<Double>(G.V());
    pq.insert(s, distTo[s]);

    while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
        int v = pq.delMin();
        for (DirectedEdge e : G.adj(v))
            relax(e);

    }


    // check optimality conditions
    assert check(G, s);
}

// relax edge e and updat e pq if changed
private void relax(DirectedEdge e) {
    int v = e.from(), w = e.to();
    if (distTo[w] > distTo[v] + e.weight()) {
        distTo[w] = distTo[v] + e.weight();
        edgeTo[w] = e;
        if (pq.contains(w)) pq.decreaseKey(w, distTo[w]);
        else   {
            pq.insert(w, distTo[w]);                
        }            
    }

}

public int getLength() {
    return length;
}

public IndexMinPQ<Double> getPq() {
    return pq;
}

/**
 * Returns the length of a shortest path from the source vertex <tt>s</tt> to vertex <tt>v</tt>.
 * @param v the destination vertex
 * @return the length of a shortest path from the source vertex <tt>s</tt> to vertex <tt>v</tt>;
 *    <tt>Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY</tt> if no such path
 */
public double distTo(int v) {
    return distTo[v];
}

/**
 * Is there a path from the source vertex <tt>s</tt> to vertex <tt>v</tt>?
 * @param v the destination vertex
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if there is a path from the source vertex
 *    <tt>s</tt> to vertex <tt>v</tt>, and <tt>false</tt> otherwise
 */
public boolean hasPathTo(int v) {
    return distTo[v] < Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
}

/**
 * Returns a shortest path from the source vertex <tt>s</tt> to vertex <tt>v</tt>.
 * @param v the destination vertex
 * @return a shortest path from the source vertex <tt>s</tt> to vertex <tt>v</tt>
 *    as an iterable of edges, and <tt>null</tt> if no such path
 */
public Iterable<DirectedEdge> pathTo(int v) {
    if (!hasPathTo(v)) return null;
    Stack<DirectedEdge> path = new Stack<DirectedEdge>();
    for (DirectedEdge e = edgeTo[v]; e != null; e = edgeTo[e.from()]) {
        path.push(e);
        length++;
    }
    return path;
}


// check optimality conditions:
// (i) for all edges e:            distTo[e.to()] <= distTo[e.from()] + e.weight()
// (ii) for all edge e on the SPT: distTo[e.to()] == distTo[e.from()] + e.weight()
private boolean check(EdgeWeightedDigraph G, int s) {

    // check that edge weights are nonnegative
    for (DirectedEdge e : G.edges()) {
        if (e.weight() < 0) {
            System.err.println("negative edge weight detected");
            return false;
        }
    }

    // check that distTo[v] and edgeTo[v] are consistent
    if (distTo[s] != 0.0 || edgeTo[s] != null) {
        System.err.println("distTo[s] and edgeTo[s] inconsistent");
        return false;
    }
    for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++) {
        if (v == s) continue;
        if (edgeTo[v] == null && distTo[v] != Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
            System.err.println("distTo[] and edgeTo[] inconsistent");
            return false;
        }
    }

    // check that all edges e = v->w satisfy distTo[w] <= distTo[v] + e.weight()
    for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++) {
        for (DirectedEdge e : G.adj(v)) {
            int w = e.to();
            if (distTo[v] + e.weight() < distTo[w]) {
                System.err.println("edge " + e + " not relaxed");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // check that all edges e = v->w on SPT satisfy distTo[w] == distTo[v] + e.weight()
    for (int w = 0; w < G.V(); w++) {
        if (edgeTo[w] == null) continue;
        DirectedEdge e = edgeTo[w];
        int v = e.from();
        if (w != e.to()) return false;
        if (distTo[v] + e.weight() != distTo[w]) {
            System.err.println("edge " + e + " on shortest path not tight");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
 }
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: How do I count the number of checked vertices?

Answer (score 1):

> finding the amount of vertices that have been checked isn't really working.

Every time you pop a vertex from the queue, increment a counter (let's call it vertexCounter):

```
int vertexCounter = 0;
while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
    int v = pq.delMin();
    vertexCounter++;
    for (DirectedEdge e : G.adj(v))
        relax(e);
}
```

By the way, you should improve the names of all variables and methods. It's hard to read your code.

Comment: Thanks for ur fast answer. However I have already tried this and all it does is count the maximum number of vertices, not the vertices that have been checked... for all my maps it will return 1200 (30x40 maps so always 1200 vertices)
Sorry for the variables, Sedgewick is indeed not very practical with his variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of checked vertices by adding variable to your class and increase it inside the method relax(e). So if we assume that the variable name is: numberOfCheckedVertices

```
private int numberOfCheckedVertices;
```

Increasing the amount of the variable should happen here:

```
private void relax(DirectedEdge e) {
//increase the amount of visited vertices
numberOfCheckedVertices++;
int v = e.from(), w = e.to();
if (distTo[w] > distTo[v] + e.weight()) {
    distTo[w] = distTo[v] + e.weight();
    edgeTo[w] = e;
    if (pq.contains(w)) pq.decreaseKey(w, distTo[w]);
    else   {
        pq.insert(w, distTo[w]);                
    }            
}}
```

Maybe you will ask why inside that method? Because when you we call the method relax(e) you have actually checked the node(vertex)